# recover value of Jtextfield (non-static variable JTextField2 cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, netbeans

this is my code

```
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/*
* OneFace.java
*
* Created on 9 mars 2015, 17:52:26
*/
package org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
*
* @author TENNI
*/
public class OneFace extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setLayout(null);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ravie", 0, 18));
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel1.setText(" Welcome to MyCloud");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(200, 30, 260, 40);

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel2.setText("Enter the number of Host:");
    jLabel2.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(250, 110, 160, 20);
                         jLayeredPane1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter the characteristic of Host"));
    jLayeredPane1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel3.setText("Host ID");
    jLabel3.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel3.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setBounds(40, 30, 60, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel4.setText("Pes Nbr");
    jLabel4.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel4.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel4.setBounds(30, 60, 70, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel5.setText("BW");
    jLabel5.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel5.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel5.setBounds(60, 90, 40, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel6.setText("RAM");
    jLabel6.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel6.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel6.setBounds(250, 30, 50, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel6, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
    jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel7.setText("Storage");
    jLabel7.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jLabel7.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel7.setBounds(240, 60, 60, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel7, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField1.setText("  ");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jTextField1.setBounds(110, 30, 100, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField2.setText("  ");
    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jTextField2.setBounds(110, 60, 100, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField3.setText("  ");
    jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jTextField3.setBounds(110, 90, 100, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField4.setText("  ");
    jTextField4.setBounds(310, 30, 100, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField5.setText("  ");
    jTextField5.setBounds(310, 60, 100, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel8.setText("\n");
    jLabel8.setBounds(280, 100, 0, 14);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel8, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabel9.setText("\n");
    jLabel9.setBounds(290, 90, 0, 14);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel9, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextField7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField7.setText("  ");
    jTextField7.setBounds(510, 100, 0, 20);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextField7, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jPanel1.add(jLayeredPane1);
    jLayeredPane1.setBounds(60, 200, 510, 120);

    jToggleButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tunga", 1, 18));
    jToggleButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 153));
    jToggleButton1.setText("Next");
    jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jToggleButton1);
    jToggleButton1.setBounds(280, 330, 80, 30);

    jTextField6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField6.setText("  Nbr Hosts");
    jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jTextField6);
    jTextField6.setBounds(270, 140, 80, 20);

    jTextField8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
    jTextField8.setText("  ");
    jPanel1.add(jTextField8);
    jTextField8.setBounds(10, 0, 12, 20);

    jLabel10.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\TENNI\\Pictures\\app\\278970_Large_20141027075248_12.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.add(jLabel10);
    jLabel10.setBounds(0, 0, 670, 370);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new       javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 662, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:



}                                              

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
// End of variables declaration

public JTextField nbr; 
public JTextField hostid; 
public JTextField pes; 
public JTextField bw; 
public JTextField ram; 
public JTextField storage;
private Object JTextField1;
private Object JTextField2;
private Object JTextField3;
private Object JTextField4;
private Object JTextField5;
private Object JTextField6;



 public static JTextField getJTextField2() {
      return jTextField2;
 }



/** Creates new form OneFace */
public OneFace() {
    initComponents();

    /*instanciation des JTEXTfield*/ 
nbr=new JTextField(6); 
hostid=new JTextField(1); 
pes=new JTextField(2); 
bw=new JTextField(3); 
ram=new JTextField(4); 
storage=new JTextField(5); 
}

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new OneFace().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

How can i recover my values which is input in a jTextField;
in this code in line 283 i an error.
(non-static variable JTextField2 cannot be referenced from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a non-static field from a static method, because there is no way for Java to know which instance you want to get the field from.

The error is in this method:

```
public static JTextField getJTextField2() {
    return jTextField2;
}
```

Remove the `static` modifier to fix the problem:

```
public JTextField getJTextField2() {
    return jTextField2;
}
```

Comment: Thanhs Erwin i have resolute my problem